APACHE HOP - S3 File Plugin - HopException: Missing transform plugin
We are currently migrating our PDI to Apache Hop, and we are encountering errors in jobs where the S3 File plugin was added.
The error message is: "HopException: Missing transform plugin for 'S3 file...'"
I'm unable to find the plugin in the Apache Hop portal.
How can I import this plugin?
Can I replace it with another action?
Are there any tips for doing this automatically?

Tks!

Apache Hop has built-in support for VFS (Virtual File System), including AWS S3. There no longer is a need for separate S3 plugins.
